# Problem about a linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Given the linear system
$$
\begin{cases}
x+y-az=b\\
ax+y-z=1\\
2x+2y-(a+1)z=2b
\end{cases}
$$
I have to determine which of the following equations

1. $a^2-2ab+b=1$
2. $a^2+b^2=0$
3. $3a-b^2+2=0$
4. $b^2+ab-a=1$
5. $2b^2-a^2+3ab=0$

is satisfied by all the pairs $(a, b)$ such that the linear system has infinite solutions.

**My attempt.** Written the augmented matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & -a & b\\
a & 1 & -1 & 1\\
2 & 2 & -(a+1) & 2b
\end{pmatrix},
$$
by reduction by rows I found (subtracting $2$ times the first row to the third row)
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & -a & b\\
a & 1 & -1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & a-1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Can I conclude that the system has infinite solutions if $a=1$ (and what about $b$?) ? But why does the exercise require an equation to be satisfied by all the pairs $(a, b)$?

Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your last matrix, if you subtract from the second row $a$ times the first row you'll get$$\begin{pmatrix}1&1&-a&b\\0&-a+1&a^2-1&-ab+1\\0&0&a-1&0\end{pmatrix}.$$Now, it is clear that the system has one and only one solution if $a\neq1$. If $a=1$, you get the matrix$$\begin{pmatrix}1&1&-1&b\\0&0&0&-b+1\\0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix},$$and therefore the system has infinitely many solutions if and only if $b=1$. Therefore, the correct option is the fourth one and only that one.

Comment: "Now, it is clear that the system has infinitely many solutions if $a\neq1$" Did you mean "has finitely many solutions"?

Comment: @5xum No. What I meant was that it has one and only one soltion in that case. I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I understand that if $a\neq 1$ the system has one and only one solution. But, if $a=1$, why does the system have infinitely many solutions if and only if $b=1$? I think that it has infinitely many solutions for every $b$, because the last row contains all $0$. Or not?

Comment: @Redeldio No. Think about the *second* line. If you think in terms of equations, it says that $0\times x+0\times y+0\times z=-b+1$. If $b\neq1$, then this equation has *zero* solutions.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Ok, I think in terms of ranks of the matrix $A$ and the matrix $A|b$. Tell me if my attempt is correct. If $a=1$, since rank$(A)$ is $1$, the system admits solutions if and only if rank$(A|b)$ is $1$. But if $b\neq 1$, rank$(A|b)$ is $2$. So the system admits (infinitely many) solutions if and only if $b=1$. Is it right? Thank You

Comment: @Redeldio That's right if you add to it that the rank of the augmented matrix is $1$ when $b=1$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yes, I understood it in the last sentence. Thank You

Answer (score 2):

If $a=1$ then

$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & -a & b\\
a & 1 & -1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & a-1 & 0
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & -1 & b\\
1 & 1 & -1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$ and you see that $b=1$.

The pair $(a,b)=(1,1)$ satiesfies $b^2+ab-a=1$.

Answer (score 0):

By careful observation, if $a=1$, the first and the third equations will be dependent. So the third equation can be ignored, leaving:
$$\begin{cases} x+y-z=b \\ x+y-z=1\end{cases}$$
If $b\ne 1$, there is no solution. If $b=1$, there is one equation with three unknowns. Thus it has infinitely many solutions. The result follows.